# PowerShell code to tie a firewall rule to a WindowsApps executable on Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, firewall, appx

I need to come up with PowerShell code that puts a firewall rule in place, where this rule is tied to an executable that, in its turn, comes from an installed AppX package. The executable, thus, sits beneath C:\Program Files\WindowsApps.

Firewall rules can be tied to executables but is this the right approach in the case of an executable sitting beneath C:\Program Files\WindowsApps in the first place?

Comment: I think each app already has a firewall rule.  `Get-NetFirewallApplicationFilter`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done!

1. Open an elevated powershell window
2. Run the command `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers` and find the name of the package you want (ie - *Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.0.22000.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe*)
3. Open the directory and find the executable file in there, and make a note of the full path
4. Create a new firewall rule with powershell:
   a. `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow Inbound Port 80 for Windows Calculator" -Direction Inbound -LocalPort 80 -Program "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.0.22000.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\calculator.exe" -Action Allow`

Comment: Thanks, so it's the right approach to refer to the AppX executable just like to any other executable?